# Node.js Headless Web Scraping with Webdriver.io + Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium

I need to use headless Selenium in Node.js for scraping. I tried Webdriver.io, it worked with non-headless Selenium. But when I run headless Selenium, it didn't work at all. Here is the code (the same as on the webdriver.io example)

```
webdriverio
  .remote(options)
  .init()
  .url('http://www.google.com')
  .getTitle().then(function(title) {
  console.log('Title was: ' + title);
})
  .end();
```

How to make it work with headless Selenium? Or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up selenium in headless environment. Try xvfb - that's headless gui for firefox.

```
$ apt-get install fvfb -y
$ DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score -2):

I've done lots of scraping with different libraries in the past, and unless you need to do login, or manipulate the page then I recommend you use [request](https://github.com/request/request) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to handle your scraping.  That permits you to scrape your content using jQuery styled filtering.  It also lets you perform the scraping without any dependency on anything else like Selenium or PhantomJS.

Quick example:

```js
request('http://www.google.com', (err, response, body) => {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    const title = $('title').text();
    console.log(`Title was: ${title}`);
    // Or scrape whatever you want from the page
});
```

If you need to handle logging in, handling forms, or performing any actions on the page before you scrape it you can try any number of libraries.  I've used [Zombie.js](http://zombie.js.org/) with decent results and tried several others like Selenium [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) (uses PhantomJS), PhantomJS, and others.

In the end Request and Cheerio have made it pretty easy to quickly scrape a page.

Comment: I know cheerio and have used it along with request before. The problem with request is sometimes it doesn't return the HTML as we see on the browser, so it's impossible to parse the HTML with cheerio. For example for this page indotrading.com/companycatalog/. I only need to find a way to get the HTML code, then load it with cheerio.

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks like you're trying to scrape some dynamic sites..  [nightmarejs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) was friendly but I hated having the PhantomJS dependency.  Zombie.js has evolved into a browser testing framework, but I have used it numerous times in the past because it had no dependency on another toolkit.

Comment: fwiw, nightmare.js no longer has a phantomjs dependency (removed about a year ago). it now runs entirely on electron.